# stop jquery slideshow at the last image

Tags: jquery, slideshow, fotorama

I am using Fotorama for my slideshow but does not have an option among the presets to stop the slide on the last image...

the following script contains the navigation buttons and I am posting it because maybe it may be helpful...I have been looking into it but I am not familiar with coding jquery...but I am trying to understand it

I notice how the is a var size - 5 that tells the script how many slides there are...
and there is the var intervalInput = $('#fotorama-interval'); that I think may be needed to tell the slideshow that it reached the last image?

please help me if you can

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        var $document = $(document);
        var stage = $('#chromeless-stage');
        var control = $('#fotorama-control');
        var fotorama = $('#fotorama');

        var activeIndex;
        var arrows = $('#fotorama-arrows').find('input');
        var thumbs = $('#fotorama-thumbs').find('a');

        var size = 5;

        // FOTORAMA
        fotorama.fotorama({
            data: [
                {img: 'images/start-slide-1.jpg'},
                {img: 'images/start-slide-2.jpg'},
                {img: 'images/start-slide-3.jpg'},
                {img: 'images/start-slide-4.jpg'},
                {img: 'images/start-slide-5.jpg'}

            ],
            width: '100%',
            height: 'auto',
            minHeight: 600,
            fitToWindowHeight: true,
            fitToWindowHeightMargin: 0,
            margin: 0,
            cropToFit: true,
            shadows: false,
            transitionDuration: 888,
            loop: true,
            autoplay: 2500,
            stopAutoplayOnAction: false,
            transition: 'fade', 
            nav: 'none', 
            arrows: false,

            onClick: function(data)
            { window.location = 'about-ana-parzych-custom-cakes.html' },

            /*transition: fade,*/

            onShowImg: function(data, auto) {
                if (!auto && playingFLAG) {
                    pause();
                }
                activeIndex = data.index;
                thumbs.not(
                        thumbs.eq(activeIndex).addClass('active')
                    ).removeClass('active');

                if (activeIndex == 0) {
                    arrows.slice(0,2).attr({disabled: 'disabled'});
                } else {
                    arrows.slice(0,2).removeAttr('disabled');
                }

                if (activeIndex == size - 1) {
                    arrows.slice(2).attr({disabled: 'disabled'});
                } else {
                    arrows.slice(2).removeAttr('disabled');
                }
            }
        });

        // SLIDESHOW
        var playButton = $('#fotorama-play');
        var pauseButton = $('#fotorama-pause');
        var intervalInput = $('#fotorama-interval');

        var playingFLAG = false;

        function changeThumbBorderColor() {
            thumbs.parent()[(playingFLAG ? 'add' : 'remove') + 'Class']('autoplay');
        }

        function start() {
            fotorama.trigger('play'); // Start playing
            playingFLAG = false;

            playButton.attr('disabled', 'disabled');
            pauseButton.removeAttr('disabled');
            changeThumbBorderColor();
        }

        function pause() {
            fotorama.trigger('pause'); // Pause
            playingFLAG = true;

            pauseButton.attr('disabled', 'disabled');
            playButton.removeAttr('disabled');
            changeThumbBorderColor();
        }

        playButton.click(start);
        pauseButton.click(pause);

        // Custom interval
        intervalInput.bind('click change keypress cut copy paste input', function(){
            fotorama.data('options').autoplay = intervalInput.val()*1000;
            if (playingFLAG) {
                fotorama.trigger('pause');
                fotorama.trigger('play');
            }
        });

        // CUSTOM THUMBS AND ARROWS
        arrows.bind('click', function(){
            var index = $(this).attr('data-action');
            if (index == 'next') {
                index = activeIndex + 1;
            } else if (index == 'prev') {
                index = activeIndex - 1;
            }

            if (index > size - 1) {
                index = size - 1;
            }

            if (index < 0) {
                index = 0;
            }

            fotorama.trigger('showimg', index);
        });

        thumbs.bind('click', function(e){
            fotorama.trigger('showimg', thumbs.index(this));
            return false;
        });

        $document.bind('keydown', function(e){
            if (!fotorama.hasClass('fotorama_fullscreen') && !intervalInput.is(':focus')) {
                if (e.keyCode == 39 || e.keyCode == 40) {
                    fotorama.trigger('showimg', 'next');
                    return false;
                } else if (e.keyCode == 37 || e.keyCode == 38) {
                    fotorama.trigger('showimg', 'prev');
                    return false;
                }
            }
        });

        // FULLSCREEN
        $('#fotorama-fullscreen').bind('click', function(){
            fotorama.trigger('fullscreenopen');
        });

        // RESCALE
        /*var rescale = $('#fotorama-rescale').find('input');
        rescale.bind('click', function(){
            var $this = $(this);
            rescale.not(
                    $this.attr({disabled: 'disabled'})
                ).removeAttr('disabled');
            var newSize = $this.val().split(', ');
            var width = newSize[0];
            var height = newSize[1];
            if (width == '100%') {
                width = stage.width();
                control.css({width: '50%'});
            } else {
                control.css({width: ''});
            }

            fotorama.trigger('rescale', [width, false, 700/467, 333]);
        });*/
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use Fotorama 3:

```
var fotorama = $('#fotorama');
fotorama.fotorama({
    onShowImg: function () {
        var data = fotorama.data();
        if (data.size - data.index === 1) {
            fotorama.trigger('pause');
        } 
    }
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/artpolikarpov/67e4q/12/

Fotorama 4 has a different API:

```
$('.fotorama').on('fotorama:showend', function (e, fotorama) {
    if (fotorama.size - fotorama.activeIndex === 1) {
        fotorama.stopAutoplay();
    }
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/artpolikarpov/HRzdw/